# PostGis clustering with other aggregate

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I would like to compute cluster of points and, for each cluster to get the sum of a specific attribute (let say, the sum of the score of each point in the cluster)

I already managed to build clusters using `ST_ClusterWithin` but I cannot compute the sum.

Here is what I tried :

```
SELECT sum(score), unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(coordinates, 0.1)) AS cluster
FROM locations
GROUP BY cluster;
```

But I get the following error `ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY`

If I remove the `GROUP BY`, I get the sum of the score for all locations, which is not what I want (I want the sum for locations in the cluster)

Comment: Try wraping it with another select, and do the group by in the outer select .... SELECT sum,cluster FROM(YOUR QUERY) group by cluster

Comment: Can't get it working. In order to sum in my outer query, I need either to group or to aggregate the score attribute in my inner query (because ST_Clusterwithin is already an aggregate function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a tricky one and the st_clusterwithin api doesn't seem well designed for what should be a common case.

The only solution I could find was to rejoin back on the clusters as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(score), cluster FROM locations, (
    SELECT unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(coordinates, 0.1)) AS cluster
    FROM locations
) as location_clustered
WHERE ST_Contains(ST_CollectionExtract(cluster, 1), coordinates)
GROUP BY cluster;
```

Edit: I've changed `ST_CollectionHomogenize` to `ST_CollectionExtract(<geometrycollection>, 1)` (Pick `1` for point, `2` for linestring and `3` for polygon) as suggested in this answer:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195915/
because of this bug: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3569

Don't ask me why you can't do `ST_Contains(<geometrycollection>, <geometry>)`; 
We need to convert to a multipoint which is permissable as an argument.

Meta: this question would have been a great match for https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Should that be "FROM locations," instead of "FROM location," in the outer select?

Answer (score 2):

With PostGIS 2.3, one might profit from the [ST_ClusterDBSCAN](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html) function (the choice of the third parameter reduces it to hierarchical clustering) which returns directly the corresponding cluster index:

```
WITH stat AS (
  SELECT
    score, ST_ClusterDBSCAN(coordinates, 0.1, 1) OVER () AS cluster_id
  FROM
    tmp_locations
)
SELECT
  cluster_id, SUM(score)
FROM
  stat
GROUP BY
  cluster_id
ORDER BY
  cluster_id
```